# Webview.loadDataWithBaseURL with Referer and Asset

Tags: android

New twist to an old question. How to load html into a webview with a "Referer"/Referrer and load files from asset or drawable directories.

Loading with a "Referer" or Referrer.

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("www.refererurl.com", html, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Using the `www.refererurl.com` will prevent assets from being loaded.

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Using null for the first param will load from the assets if the html contains something like:

```
file:///android_asset/ic_launcher.png
```

So how do I do both, load from assets and load from with a referer?

Comment: For a fully-qualified URL (`file:///...`) in the HTML, the `baseURL` (first parameter to `loadDataWithBaseURL()`) should not matter.

Comment: I agree it should not matter but from all my testing if I put `file:///...` into the html the asset never loads. Tested several ways to ensure the path was valid but they still won't load. *When loading with a referer url* @CommonsWare

Answer (score 0):

If I read the documentation correctly looks like you cannot load with a referer and load assets.

From the webview docs on loadDataWithBaseURL:

```
 * Note that content specified in this way can access local device files
 * (via 'file' scheme URLs) only if baseUrl specifies a scheme other than
 * 'http', 'https', 'ftp', 'ftps', 'about' or 'javascript'.
```